# Why the distribution key cannot be updated in Netezza

Tags: sql, sql-update, netezza

I tried updating the distribution key in Netezza but I am getting the below error.What could be the reason for this error?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says that `AD_START_DAY_KEY` is a distribution column, and that distribution columns can't be updated.

From [DB Technology: Netezza Questions and Answers](http://techdb.wordpress.com/2009/08/02/netezza-questions-and-answers/):

> **When no distribution clause is used while creating a table, what distribution is used by Netezza.**
>   First column (same as in Teradata).
>
> **Can we update all columns in a Netezza table.**
>   No, the column that is used in distribution clause cannot be used for updates. Remember, up to four columns can be used for distribution of data on SPU. From practical sense, updating distribution columns result in redistribution of data; the single most performance hit when large table is involved. This restriction makes sense.

A work-around would be to delete the row, and insert a new one.